# Robot Framework - Appium Swipe / Scroll down does not perform Swipe / Scrolling action

Tags: android, appium, robotframework, node-modules, appium-android

I am trying to do a swipe up action on the app I am testing, Below is the code:

```
Test for Navigation to Directory
    run keyword and continue on failure  Tap on Bottom Navigation icon  Directory
    run keyword and continue on failure     wait until page contains  Police
#   swipe by percent    50     50     50    70  2000
#   Swipe By Direction  up
    swipe   100 700 100 1000    2000
#   scroll down     xpath=/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/iveLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/.....
    sleep  2s
    page should contain text  Ticketing
```

As we can see, I tried almost all methods in Appium Library to trigger the swipe, but nothing works. The Screen remains unchanged and shows only the icons at the top, and does not scroll to any icons which are below the initial screen.

Also, Swipe By Direction does not get recognized as a Keyword despite it is mentioned in the [keyword documentation](https://serhatbolsu.github.io/robotframework-appiumlibrary/AppiumLibrary.html)

My Test Device is a Samsung Note 8 with Android 9 . Is there any way to trigger the swipe up action?

Answer (score 2):

Finally, Swipe by Percent worked fine. I made a mistake in the earlier code when setting the Y coordinates. The below code finally worked for me.

```
swipe by percent    50     50     50    70  2000
```